# JDL: Found groupable relationship "OneToOne"

Tags: visual-studio-code, jhipster, jdl

I am new to JHipster and am creating a new project with the following Entity definition:

```
enum AccountType {
    CHECKING, SAVINGS
}

enum TransactionType {
    CHECK, DEPOSIT, WITHDRAWAL
}

enum EnvelopeType {
    INCOME, EXPENSE
}

// The name 'Account' is a reserved keyword and can not be used as an entity class name.
entity Ledger {
    name String required
    type AccountType
    memo String
    accountNumber String
    routingNumber String
}

entity Envelope {
    name String required
    type EnvelopeType
    memo String
}

entity Transaction {
    name String required
    type TransactionType
    memo String
    amount BigDecimal
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Transaction to Envelope
}

relationship OneToMany {
  Ledger to Transaction
}
```

Within VS Code, I get the following warnings:

- Found groupable relationship "OneToOne"
- Found groupable relationship "OneToMany"

It is unclear what each of these relationships can be grouped with to quash the warnings.

Comment: It could be a bug, you could report it to https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-ide

Comment: I was getting this warning and found that it was solved by having only one `OneToMany` block with all the relationships defined therein.  Previously, I had been using multiple blocks of each type for clarity in the file.

I'm not sure if you have more JDL than you have listed here because you don't seem to have the same situation.  Perhaps it was a bug in your case.